# share code between very similar methods

Tags: c++

My job is to fully rewrite an old library for GIS vector data processing. The main class encapsulates a collection of building outlines, and offers different methods for checking data consistency. Those checking functions have an optional parameter that allows to perform some process.

For instance:

```
std::vector<Point> checkIntersections(int process_mode = 0);
```

This method tests if some building outlines are intersecting, and return the intersection points. But if you pass a non null argument, the method will modify the outlines to remove the intersection.

I think it's pretty bad (at call site, a reader not familiar with the code base will assume that a method called checkSomething only performs a check and doesn't modifiy data) and I want to change this. I also want to avoid code duplication as check and process methods are mostly similar.

So I was thinking to something like this:

```
// a private worker
std::vector<Point> workerIntersections(int process_mode = 0)
{
    // it's the equivalent of the current checkIntersections, it may perform
    // a process depending on process_mode
}


// public interfaces for check and process
std::vector<Point> checkIntersections()  /* const */
{
    workerIntersections(0);
}


std::vector<Point> processIntersections(int process_mode /*I have different process modes*/)
{
    workerIntersections(process_mode);
}
```

But that forces me to break const correctness as workerIntersections is a non-const method.

How can I separate check and process, avoiding code duplication and keeping const-correctness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you've noted, your suggestion will break `const-correctness`.
This is because your suggestion essentially includes wrapping the existing code with a new `interface` but not the `redesign` of internals. This approach has severe limitations as it's directly affected by the underlying blocks.

Instead I would suggest you to redesign the existing code and just break the `checkIntersections` in 2 public methods that you need. The `checkIntersections` will include the checking part and `processIntersections` will include the call to `checkIntersections` and the processing code based on the result of `checkIntersections`.

Comment: I've chosen the way of complete redisign, as you suggested. It will take way more time, but result will be way better.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, breaking const-correctness shouldn't matter. You (as the author of `workerIntersections()` **know** that it will only perform non-const operations if invoked from `processIntersections()`, a non-const function. Therefore, it's safe to implement `checkIntersections()` like this:

```
std::vector<Point> checkIntersections() const
{
    const_cast<TypeOfThis*>(this)->workerIntersections(0);
}
```

Of course, you must make sure that `workerIntersections()` really only does const operations when invoked with `0`.

`const_cast` exists in the language for a reason, mainly interoperability with legacy code which ignores const correctness. That's exactly what you're doing, so as long as you do it safely, you're fine using `const_cast`.